# What does grep * do?

Tags: bash, grep

I'm reading [this tutorial](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html)

and there is this line:

```
    grep da * 2> grep-errors.txt
```

It is too cryptic and the author does not break down the syntax.

Comment: the line from the tute is `grep da * 2> grep-errors.txt` which means look for da in all files in directory and write stderr to grep-errors.txt

Comment: but wha does the `* 2` do ?

Comment: `2> grep-errors.txt` means "write stderr to grep-errors.txt". *"It is too cryptic"*. Shell syntax is often cryptic. If you want to fix that you will need a time machine. Set the dial to about 1976, and the location to Bell Labs, Murray Hill, New Jersey. And have a chat to the author. (Or just learn to live with it.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should split the command in parts to understand:

- `grep`
  Global REgular Print: Look for lines over all input (from stream or inputfiles) containing a string (possible regular expression) end show it.
- `da`
  String to look for (as in Adam dances daily: three hits)
- `*`
  Before grep starts, the shell already has replaced the Wildcard with all files in the current directory. When the current directory is empty, the shell will give the character to grep and grep tries to look for a file called `*`.
- `2> grep-errors.txt`
  grep will not see this, this is an instruction for the shell that the output stream 2 must be redirected to a file called with the name grep-errors.txt.
  Stream 2? Yes, 1 is normal and 2 is for error messages.

Comment: Thanks for the less in cryptology.

Answer (score 4):

Note that it is not `* 2` as you read it but `* 2>` which is something very different.

`2>` is a redirection operator that redirects the standard error stream, like `>` alone redirects standard output.